# Can we rename a file or directory in azure files

Tags: azure-files

Can we have any provision to rename the file or directory name in azure files without start copy method?

We already tried start copy method, we don't want that method.

Comment: powershell or c#?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no such **rename** the file or directory feature, you have to use start copy method. You can vote for the feature [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/4041042-rename-blobs-without-needing-to-copy-them) to improve the product.

You also could get more reference from this blog: [Rename Azure Storage Blob using PowerShell](https://about-azure.com/2018/02/13/rename-azure-storage-blob-using-powershell/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible.As such there is no API to rename a file and/or folder in a file share in your Azure Storage account. Cerebrata is the only tool available in the market which enables you to do that. Apart from the basic functionality like renaming a file or folder, Cerebrata also offers additional functionality to preserve SMB information like file creation time etc. while performing the rename operation. All of this without writing a single line of code. 
Kindly refer to this article I wrote [Rename Files and Folders in Azure File Storage](https://cerebrata.com/blog/renaming-files-and-folders-in-azure-file-storage)

Comment: When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.